# Azure, Increase Worker Count Programatically, Management API / Cmdlets? (without reboot)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell-cmdlet, azure-powershell

I need to be able to increase the number of worker instances on in cloud service deployment from code.

So far i have found these two options:

1) I have been able to use the Change Deployment Configuration from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee460809 and this works, however it reboots all instances of that worker instead of just addding one, its a deployment configuration change so that makes sense.

The ChangeConfiguration:

```
var xml = "<ChangeConfiguration xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\">" +
"<Configuration>" + base64Value + "</Configuration>" +
"<TreatWarningsAsError>false</TreatWarningsAsError>" +
"<Mode>Auto</Mode>" +
"</ChangeConfiguration>";
```

2) The other option is using the azure Cmdlet "Set-AzureRole" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495223.aspx - I have not yet management to get this working from my developement environment so don't know what effect this has on other currently running instances. If this does work, has anyone been able to run Cmdlets from a worker role in the cloud?

Am i missing something with option 1? To not reboot on change? or are there other ways to acheive this change within code?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Set-AzureRole doesn't seem to reboot the running instances. So might be the way forward. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Does PowerShell work for you? It is still `code`. If it works, there is fairly easy way, check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092979/how-to-update-an-azure-cloud-service-setting-using-azure-powershell/26093922#26093922

Comment: BTW, reboot does not come from Azure autmatically, but from the way you handle RoleEnvironmentChanging/Changed events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changed.aspx default behavior of old school programmers were to automatically reboot the instance. Which is not needed if you know what to do.